# How to priorize CDI Interceptor over JAX-RS ExceptionMapper

Tags: java, jax-rs, cdi, interceptor, exceptionmapper

I have a REST webservice that manage its transactions using the following approach:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface TransactionRequired {

}

@Interceptor
@TransactionRequired
public class TransactionRequiredInterceptor {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object manageTransaction(InvocationContext ctx) {
        try { 
            ..start transaction..
        }
        catch(Exception e) { 
            ..rollback.. 
        }
    }
}
```

And I am also mapping my exceptions like this:

```
@Provider
public class RuntimeExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(RuntimeException exception) {
        .. return some response..
    }

}
```

The issue is that when, lets say, an RuntimeException is thrown (after transaction being started), it is immediatelly intercepted by the **RuntimeExceptionMapper** and the transaction is never rollbacked.

Being so, I need a way to priorize the **TransactionRequiredInterceptor**..

Obs: Using @Transactional is not an option since I need to deploy on Tomcat 8.

Comment: Sounds like you are intercepting the entire resource method. I'm guessing you are calling the EM inside the resource method. Why don't you add a DAO layer and intercept the DAO calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO what you are asking doesn't make sense. Because your JAX-RS library doesn't have to implement an exception mapping via interceptors.

But still your `TransactionRequiredInterceptor` can respond to the exception by using a `finally` block - because JVM always (almost) guarantee its execution.

**Anyway, I doubt if it's a good idea**.

Firstly, a much better way, would be to have additional layer (let's call it `service` or `dao`) and intercept such class methods.

Secondly, you can be 100% sure that your implementation of the transaction management will have plethora of bugs. IMHO in your case (CDI and Tomcat) the best way to go is [DeltaSpike](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jpa.html) because it already gives you such `@Transactional` interceptor: `org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.transaction.Transactional`. I use it personally with a great success.

BTW: you can try Apache DeltaSpike also due to many other useful features - they can save you many headaches.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me :)

Comment: Additionally, CDI already provides ```@Transactional``` interceptor just for this

Comment: @maress Nope. `@javax.transaction.Transactional` is just an annotation. CDI itself doesn't provide you any interceptor handling this annotation - thus it will be silently skipped :-)  `@Transactional` is taken into account out of the box only when EJB3 transactions are present on the classpath (e.g. in the Java EE server).